# Trying to reference another column to fill in a new column with matching data using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

Sorry Im still new at this so I might be missing something fairly simple. My question is this, how do I get the Captain's Name extracted into a new column to match the team (ie David Fournier with the Marlins)? I feel Im missing something quite simple with a self join. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's my first query...

```
SELECT 
    b.BowlerID, 
    concat (b.BowlerFirstName,'  ',b.BowlerLastName) 'Bowler's Name', 
    t.TeamName, 
    t.CaptainID
FROM Bowlers as b
INNER JOIN Teams as t ON b.TeamID = t.TeamID
```

Result is this...

```
BowlerID   Bowler's Name           TeamName    CaptainID
1          Barbara Fournier        Marlins       2
2          David Fournier          Marlins       2
3          John Kennedy            Marlins       2
4          Sara Sheskey            Marlins       2
5          Ann Patterson           Sharks        5
6          Neil Patterson          Sharks        5
7          David Viescas           Sharks        5
8          Stephanie Viescas       Sharks        5
```

and another query i ran...

```
SELECT 
    b.BowlerID, 
    concat (b.BowlerFirstName,'  ',b.BowlerLastName) 'Team Captain', 
    t.TeamName
FROM Bowlers as b
INNER JOIN Teams as t ON b.BowlerID = t.CaptainID
```

gets me this...

```
BowlerID    Team Captain      TeamName
2           David Fournier    Marlins
5           Ann Patterson     Sharks
```

Comment: You can join the same table more than once as long as you use table aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join `Bowlers` one more time to get the captain name:

```
SELECT 
    b.BowlerID, 
    CONCAT(b.BowlerFirstName, ' ', b.BowlerLastName) [Bowler Name], 
    t.TeamName, 
    t.CaptainID,
    CONCAT(c.BowlerFirstName, ' ', c.BowlerLastName) [Captain Name]
FROM Bowlers as b
INNER JOIN Teams as t ON b.TeamID = t.TeamID
INNER JOIN Bowlers as c ON  c.BowlerID = t.CaptainID
```

Note: in SQL server, you would better use square brackets (`[]`) to quote identifiers; single quotes are usually reserved to string litterals.

Comment: I really wish that Microsoft deprecated all string literal aliasing, and not just `'Alias' = {Expression}`.

Comment: @Larnu: indeed... I think that SQL-Server is one of the last RDBMS that allows that...

Comment: Damn I thought I tried that but I think I was dolt and missed it .Thanks! And thanks for the tip on the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could do this with conditional aggregation and a windowed function:

```
MAX(
    CASE WHEN T.CaptainID = B.BowlerID 
        THEN CONCAT(B.BowlerFirstName,'  ',B.BowlerLastName) 
    END
) OVER (PARTITION BY T.TeamID)
```